# jQuery Select div ID issue

Tags: jquery, html

I try to select "div" with id "selectmethod" but i can't !

What I need to do?

My HTML:

```
  <body>

   <div class="frame"> 
   <aside class="Aside">
   <section class="SelectProvider">
   <div class="SelectProvider-select-container" title=""> 
   <div class="SelectProvider-select-inlay">
   <div class="SelectProvider-select-image--text"></div> 
   <div class="SelectProvider-select-text">Text</div> 
   <div id="selectmethod" class="SelectProvider-select-chrome">&#9662;</div> 
   </div> 
   </div>  
   </section>   

   </aside> 
   </div> 
  </body>
```

jQ:

```
$("#selectmethod").click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: Did you make sure the jquery library was loaded correctly?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I don`t know here i find errors...
Yes, jquery library was loaded correctly

Comment: open the console (Click on F12)

Comment: No errors displayed (only css errors)

Comment: Your code works fine(https://jsfiddle.net/xc9x1mar/) assuming that you've loaded jQuery and that you're executing your code after the page has loaded

Comment: I check if is load correct and is load.

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's many reasons this could fail, but since you didn't include a complete, minimal example, it's difficult to say why it's *not* working.  Your problem is in what you *didn't* include ( namely, how the jquery code was included in the page).

However, here's a complete example that does work.

Note that here I use the `ready` function to attache the click event to the div *after* it's loaded in the page.  If you removed that and moved the script above the `div` to which it refers, the selector wouldn't match anything because the div wouldn't exist yet.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

   <div class="frame"> 
   <aside class="Aside">
   <section class="SelectProvider">
   <div class="SelectProvider-select-container" title=""> 
   <div class="SelectProvider-select-inlay">
   <div class="SelectProvider-select-image--text"></div> 
   <div class="SelectProvider-select-text">Text</div> 
   <div id="selectmethod" class="SelectProvider-select-chrome">&#9662;</div> 
   </div> 
   </div>  
   </section>   

   </aside> 
   </div> 
  <script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
     $("#selectmethod").click(function(){
      alert($(this).attr("id"));
     });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My bad, the code position was in `<head>` above jq load.